# take randomly variables in python

Tags: python

I try to found how to say it in Python : "for each loop, take 2 variables + the last one and that randomly among the variables"

Thanks for your help <3

Little exemple : (Sure the "Player" object is not there)

```
    boss = player("gigachad", 1000, 0, 0)

    a = player("robert", 1, 2, 3) 

    b = player("gilbert", 1, 2, 3)

    c = player("margeritte", 1, 2, 3)

    d = player("brigitte", 1, 2, 3)

    while(boss.get_health > 0):
    take among this 4 variables a, b, c, d, 2 of them
    (so, first loop we could have a and b )
    (second, a, b + a and c )
    (third a, b, a, c + d and b)
    (...)
```

dzadz

Comment: I Jl_Sslix, welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm a bit confused by your pseudocode notation. What does `a, b + a, c` mean? Oh, I see you've edited that section, but the new notation, `a, b + a and c` is no more clear. Are you trying to pick a random pair of values each pass through the loop? Pick one new value and combine it somehow with one of the previously selected values? In any case, I'd suggest starting by putting the values in a list, then select them using `random.choice` (or maybe `random.sample` if you need to pick two at once without any chance of repeating).

Comment: I guess the latter is ment.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not really clear. I guess you want always get two distinct from the four.
So you could do the following.

```py
import random

# your code

player_list =[ a, b, c, d]
while boss.get_health > 0:
    chosen = random.sample(player_list, 2)
```

Edit: I think I got that you want to keep the record what players were chosen. So you could  grow a list of it like that:

```py
import random

# your code

player_list =[ a, b, c, d]
chosen = []
while boss.get_health > 0:
    chosen.append(
        random.sample(player_list, 2)
    )
```

Comment: You are welcome. You can mark it as accepted then, so that your topic is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The question was not very clear, but I guess you want to sum all values, but the number of values to be summed is not always the same.

In Python, you can pass a random number of arguments to a function with Args, this way you can iterate over those values. Take a look at this example that sums a random number of values

```py
def sum_all(*args):
    sum_of_all = 0
    for arg in args:
        sum_of_all += arg
    return sum_of_all

sum_all(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
15
```

Here is a really good article with some examples.

https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/